# Prevent SystemTray from auto hiding

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any way to prevent the systemtray from auto hiding? I have this set on the xaml but it you need to click on the area, it then shows it and then shortly afterwards it auto-hides it.

shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to alter the hiding behavior of the system tray, but what data you want to display constantly?
Unfortunately there is no way to directly access the signal strength or battery life, so there is no other way to display these things to the user, but you can use the NetworkInterface class to get information about which kind of network he's connected to.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.networkinterfacetype(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: That's what I'm doing. 
    If NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable Then 
     'do stuff
    Else 
      MessageBox.Show("No Internet Connection is available, try again later.") 
    End If